# Handle empty cell in Db using SSIS

Tags: ssis, etl, data-warehouse, business-intelligence

I have a database(Source) which has a column named "country name" and few cells in it are empty & when I am transferring its data to another database (destination) it is also empty

I have tried to use derived column in which I had used REPLACE() but is didn't work I thought it would have been any "", " " or "\t" but it was neither of these then I thought may be it is NULL & I used ISNULL() but this also failed.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to work out what the "empty" data in the source column actually is? If thats the case then just convert the value to its ascii value and look that value up in an ascii table to find out what it is.

If the empty data is actually more than one character you may need to extract each character individually using, for example, the MID function.

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify which DB is in the source and which is in the target, and it has meaning.
Anyway, add this code to the Derived Column component:

```
(DT_WSTR,100)country_name == "" || ISNULL(country_name) ==  TRUE  ? "new_value" : country_name
```

**Results:**

[image]